# Bounds for probability that two elements commute in a group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, sylow-theory, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian group, and lets randomly choose two elements of $G.$ It seems quit well known that the probability that they commute is at most $\text{Pr}(G)\le\dfrac{5}{8}.$ [Here](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2018/09/16/the-5-8-theorem/) is a nice reference if you like to know more about this cute result. Equality holds if and only if $G/Z(G)\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ ( Klein four-group). Further the equality implies that each non-central conjugacy class is of order $2$ and $8\big{|}|G|.$ Smallest non-ablalian groups with this divisibility property, namely $D_8$ (dihedral group of order 8) and $Q$ (quaternion group), achieve the equality.

Next, I looked at the next possible case $G/Z(G)\cong S_3,$ and proved that here $$\dfrac{4}{9}\le\text{Pr}(G)\le\dfrac{7}{12}.$$ For example: we have $\text{Pr}(S_3)=\dfrac{1}{2}.$ But still wasn't able to find two groups that can achieve this upper and lower bound. Is it possible to reach these bound? If so, what are the examples? Otherwise, can we improve theses bounds? In general, how far can we recover a group using only inner automorphism group?

Comment: [Here are some more results](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125501/measures-of-non-abelian-ness) and references. Only some values are possible.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: That is really interesting. Thank you.

Comment: The result of MacHale mentioned in that post, which says that if the probability exceeds $\frac{1}{2}$ then it is of the form $\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2s+1}$, implies you cannot get $\frac{7}{12}$, because it is not of that form. Don’t know about $\frac{4}{9}$ off the top of my head.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I haven't look at the references mentioned in your answer. But it says we can get $\dfrac49$ either. So the actual boundes reduces to $\left[\dfrac12, \dfrac{17}{32}\right].$

Comment: Oh, right; that second clause. I was looking at the result of Joseph, which told me you needed a group of even size, as otherwise it is bounded above by $\frac{11}{27}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: And " [inner holomorph of the dihedral group of order eight](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Inner_holomorph_of_D8)" has the probability $\dfrac{17}{32}.$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: With these information, if you can write an answer to my question, that would be great. Also, what do you think/know about my last question?

Comment: My answer would just be re-hashing what I wrote in math.overflow back then, so it doesn’t seem worth it. I don’t think you can get much out of $G/Z(G)$ about $G$. For one thing, $G$ and $G\times A$ for any abelian group $G$ will have the same inner automorphism group. The two nonisomorphic nonabelian groups of order $p^3$ have $G/Z(G)\cong C_p\times C_p$. Even knowing both $G/Z(G)$ and $[G,G]$ and the commutator map $(G/Z(G))\times (G/Z(G))\to [G,G]$ only gives you the isoclinism class of $G$, you’ll get even less if you only have $G/Z(G)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I didn't know the concept "isoclinism" before. Thank you for it. (page 15 of) [P.  Lescot,  Isoclinism  classes  and  Commutativity  degrees  of  finite  groups,J.  Algebra177(1995), 847–869.](http://lmrs.math.cnrs.fr/Persopage/Lescot/P6.pdf) completely solves my problem here. I will write an answer as soon as I got some free time. Also it seems like my last question is related to group cohomology via [Schur multipliers,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_multiplier#Relation_to_central_extensions) though I know very little about them.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Do you know a good reference for these concepts?

Comment: Isoclinism is particularly useful for $p$-groups, and it was introduced by P. Hall in a 1940 paper entitled “The classification of prime-power groups”; that’s where I learned about it. There are whole books about the Schur multiplier, and about group cohomology.